# JOIN query and ANY query produced different results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I can't figure out why the following two queries would have different results.
The purpose is to list product names if there are any records in the `order details` table that quantity = 10.

```sql
SELECT products.ProductName
FROM products
INNER JOIN `order details` ON `order details`.`ProductID` = products.ProductID
WHERE `order details`.`Quantity` = 10;
```

```sql
SELECT ProductName
FROM products
WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID FROM `order details` WHERE Quantity = 10);
```

The first statement gives more results than the second one.
I am using the "Northwind sample database" in MySQL to test these SQL statements.

Can anyone tell me why these two statements would have different results, and which one is correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Imagine that there is 2 records in `order details` matched to the same record in `products`. 1st query will produce 2 output records whereas 2nd - only one record. Add DISTINCT to 1st query (or to both queries if `products.ProductName` is not unique).

Comment: you can join two table if you have primary or foreign key in  you table. try this -> SELECT p.ProductName
FROM products as p,order_details as od where od.ProductID = p.ProductID AND
od.Quantity = 10;
Here, two table are join and condition for quantity = 10.
SELECT ProductName FROM products, order_details
WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM order_details WHERE Quantity = 10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` can have two unexpected side effects:

- Rows can be filtered out because there is no match (and if the expressions used for matching are `NULL` then then are *almost* always filtered out).
- Rows can be multiplied because there are multiple matches.

Whenever you use `JOIN`, you should be thinking about these.  You are not taking the second condition into account -- there are multiple matches.

The `WHERE` clause filters rows out.  It does not generate new rows.  So duplicates in the second table do not multiple rows.